# CSS Flex with right-aligned second column wrapping to the left instead of floating between for small windows

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have three inputs. I want the top to be as wide as the content and the second two to fit between with the second column right aligned (its label left-aligned to its input box).

I've come up with this layout which works fine but I would like for the second column (Label 3) to align with the left side of the browser window if the content shrinks too much instead of floating in between.

This is what is looks like when fit to the window:

[image]

This is what is looks like when it wraps and floats in the middle (not what I want):

[image]

This is how I want it to look like when wrapping:

[image]

Can flex box and CSS do this?

```css
body {
   font-family: monospace;
   line-height: 200%;
   max-width: 600px;
}

.align-right {
   margin-left: auto;
}

.flex-row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Flex Shrink</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-row">
   <div class="flex-column">
      <label>Label 1</label>
      <input/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row">
   <div class="flex-column">
      <span>
      <label>Label 2</label>
      <br />
      <input/>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="align-right">
      <label>Label 3</label>
      <br />
      <input/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's all down to your CSS. In the `.flex-row` class I added the `justify-content: space-between;` declaration to space out the elements

Therefore there's no need for the `.margin-align-right` class anymore.

Then i removed the `flex-colum-1` class and added `flex-colum`  from the elements that you want to be spaced out so they won't have equal space of their parents

and for the element that you want to fill the space, i  added the `.flex-column-1` class to it for it to take the maximum width

```css
body {
   font-family: monospace;
   line-height: 200%;
   max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-column-1 {
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Flex Shrink</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-row">
   <div class="flex-column flex-column-1">
      <label>Label 1</label>
      <input/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row">
   <div class="flex-column">
      <span>
      <label>Label 2</label>
      <br />
      <input/>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-column">
      <span>
      <label>Label 3</label>
      <br />
      <input/>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had untick accepting this answer. It worked at first but the edits you've made since have caused it to break.

Comment: I thought you wanted the elements to take the whole width?

Comment: I did not. It might look that way in the images because I had narrowed the browser. The only issue is part where the input wraps.

Comment: Okay then... i've changed the answer back :-)